# Is the conversion of this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

We eat so that we may live.(1) -> We eat that we may live.(2)

I knew "that" in sentence (1) could be omitted, but can "so" be omitted instead of "that"?

and (1), (2) means same??

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: @gotube thank you for answer, so (1), (2) means same??

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning. The version without "so" is somewhat more poetic or dramatic.

Comment: @gotube thank you for answer